# Problems with TeXstudio

Tags: errors, texstudio

I updated my system to Ubuntu 18.04 and now I've got problems with TeXstudio.

The error message looks like this

[image: Screenshot]

I did try to reinstall texstudio (a lot times) and run all the purge and cleaning commands, but it simply doesn't work …

---

I did run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove texstudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

In between I did reboot the system, too. I visited the [official](https://www.texstudio.org) website and tried the `.deb` packages for earlier versions of Ubuntu, but it was useless.

Does anybody have an idea? Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Did you try it with the `synaptic` (→ `sudo apt-get install synaptic`) app to completely remove TeXStudio with all configurations and so on?

Comment: @current_user: I did it, too, but it doesn't work. I saw (in an eralier post from you that) you're using Ubuntu, too. Which version do you have? How can I get more attention to this question?

Comment: I don't think that you can get more attention to this question. Did you tried it on other forums (e.g. on some german ones)? Maybe there you are better helped, since that is not directly related to TeXStudio. Yes, I've got the same problem and I'm just waiting for a solution like you …

Comment: [Crosspost](https://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,102238.html#102238)

Comment: Which latex distribution are you using? How did you install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: @henry I did run the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` (of course updated).

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but sorry, I **really** need this to get fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here after upgrading to Ubutnu 18.04.1 LTS.

Removing the `.config/texstudio/texstudio.ini` file helped.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: Probably it help by accident, as it doesn't *reliably* help (e.g. in my case, Linux Mint, TeXstudio 2.12.6 (from the distro)).

Answer (score 2):

Try this from the terminal. For me it worked. Before running this go to the required directory where the deb file is located.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove texstudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i texstudio-qt4_2.12.6-2_amd64.deb
```

I had few additional issues where the icons were not displaying. So I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-qt4-4
sudo apt-get install libqt4-svg
```

If the above doesn't work, try removing texstudio completely with all its dependencies using Synaptic Package Manager and do a reinstall.

Comment: Thank you. But it says "memory access error".

Comment: try removing texstudio completely using synaptic package manager.

Comment: I did it, but it the error is still there …

Answer (score 1):

After upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04 texstudiu wasn't working and showing the meory violation like described above...
Installing Texstudiu for qt4 from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_17.04/amd64/texstudio-qt4_2.12.10-2_amd64.deb using dpkg works for me.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!